# Javascript confirm without code in code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page with dynamically added imagebuttons, and i want them to send a confirm when you click them(for deletion).

Since they are dynamic i cant code anything in a .click event.

Hows the best way to do this? check if true or false and then send it to a delete function in code behind with the control as parameter? or any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to cancel the submission, set the `OnClientClick` property to the string "Return" and the function name. The client script can then cancel the submission by returning `false`.

check imagebutton [clientclick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property.

```
void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        Label1.Text = "Server click handler called.";
    End Sub
```

your dynamic generated imagebutton should be somewhat like this:

Create commman event hadler for all imagebuttons and set the `id` of these imagebutton to the primary key value.

check [Respond to Button Web Server Control Events in Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227426%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)   for details:

You can create a custom imagebutton usercontrol that will provide the delete functionality on click event. On ItemRowCreated or GridView RowCreated events assign event hadler to these dynamically added control.

If they are not in any databind control then simple assign there properties at run time.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton();
        btn.ID = "1";
        btn.ImageUrl = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/button/256/Button-Fast-Forward-icon.png";
        btn.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Ready to submit.')";
        btn.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(btn_Click);
        this.form1.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
```

check the control id in event handler.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Image button with id = " + btn.ID + "clicked');</script>");
        }
```

and then perfom delete operation

Comment: Only problem is that i cannot set an eventhandler to btn.click, its not an option on the button.

Comment: let me know how/ where are you adding these imagebuttons on your page.. then i can suggest where to do this..

Comment: So far ive only added one, and its the same way you did... in the code behind... sorry for a late answer, my internet went out!

Comment: check the answer now.. i have updated the answer and checked it for working..   add controls at page_init or Page_load  and their event handler will definitely fire.

Comment: as i said, I cannot call the btn.click... it say that ".click is an event and cannot be called directly, use a raiseevent" also.. im doing this in vb.net, maybe there is where the problem lies?

Comment: Got it working! since i was using vb, instead of .click i had to use AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click, now it works fine!

Comment: convert this code using this [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do with jQuery (a javascript framework), even if want to do with pure JavaScript, you need to add a class to all your delete image button and add an handler to it

Using jQuery, just use this:

```
$(".deleteImageButton").bind("click", function() {
   var res = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
   return res;
});
```

Comment: Any javascript framework is ok to use, but i dont want AJAX. Im not that familiar with jquery so how would i get the response from the confirm to code behind?

Comment: You're quite unclear. What do you mean by *response from confirm*?

Comment: The reponse(true/false) from the confirmbox

Comment: You don't need to go to code behind when you click *Cancel*. Do you?

Comment: no, but when i click ok/yes i will need to remove the imagebutton and the image from a database, therefore i need to go into code behind

Comment: Clicking *OK* will request your URL on HREF of your anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble up the DOM, ie. they'll get triggered for the element it happened on, as well as all of it's parents (up to the document node itself). This make it easy to solve your problem: just attach a click handler to the container of the buttons. jQuery makes it even easier to do it through it's delegate function, here's some example code:

```
$('#buttons').delegate('.delete_control', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // maybe you don't need these 2, you can remove them if so

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete that element?')) {
        // make an ajax request to delete the image. alternatively you can submit
        // a hidden form, with the controlid in an input, but this is way simpler.
        $.post('/url/to/delete/control/by/id/' + e.target.id, function() {
            $(e.target).remove(); // to delete the button when the request is done.
        });
    }
});
```

And here's a JSFiddle page showing the whole thing working: http://jsfiddle.net/8d7D4/

Comment: That is completely unrelated to the question you asked. I've updated my code with an example though.

Answer (score 0):

Objects that fire `.click` and other functions are "collected" at load, if you add any elements after that, you need to either use `.delegate` or `.bind` to make the new elements also fire an event.

Comment: `live` has been deprecated and it's a *bad* API. Don't use that as an example. And since you copied my code and changed only that, you could have added a comment on my answer instead of posting another answer.