# How do I call a confirm popup box?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show an confirm popup  (yes, no) if an asp.net button was clicked.

If I click yes or no  it should execute some c# code.

Lets say if I click yes it will insert a record and if I click no it should update the record

Can someone give me an example on how can I achieve this? I'm really having a hard time since I'm new in javascript and c#.

Comment: I'd suggest that you read a tutorial on HTML forms, then a tutorial on introductory JavaScript, then a tutorial on C# asp.net. To paraphrase your requirement: you want to present the user with a yes/no confirmation message (JavaScript); regardless of which choice they make you want to make a request to the webserver indicating the choice as a request parameter (JavaScript form submission is an easy solution, JavaScript Ajax is a more advanced solution); you want your C# code on the webserver to handle that request and take one or another action depending on the user's selection.

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to allow the user to cancel a button they just clicked on, you can use the `OnClientClick` attribute:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" 
    OnClick="CSharpMethod" />
```

Where `CSharpMethod` is a method in your **code behind** that executes the C# lines you want run (when the user accepts the confirmation).

The signature of this method should look like this:

```
protected void CSharpMethod(object sender, EventArgs E) {
    Response.Write("Hello From Server");
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want the true of false result of the confirmation to be sent to the server, I would recommend you first create a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnConfirm" />
```

Then in your .net button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="confirmWithUser()" 
    OnClick="CSharpMethod" />
```

Then create the JavaScript function to go with the OnClientClick:

```
function confirmWithUser(){
    document.getElementById("hdnConfirm").value = confirm('Are you sure?');
}
```

In your C# method, you'll be able to get the response from the user like this:

```
protected void CSharpMethod(object sender, EventArgs E) {
    bool whatDidUserSay = Boolean.Parse(hdnConfirm.Value);

    //now do one thing or the other based on this value
}
```

Comment: My mind so quickly goes to AJAX these days that I wouldn't have even considered using an ASP.NET control... nice catch with the tag in the question!

Comment: @Steve - I know what you mean, it's like, writing that tag brings back such... **old memories** :)

Comment: OP doesn't seem to want to cancel - requirement is a yes or no prompt with either choice to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get that which button is clicked <kbd>Yes</kbd> or <kbd>No</kbd> using the button's `ClientClick` event through JavaScript only. You can control the submission of the form by returning true or false.

```
 btn.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Ready to submit.')";
```

[Javascript confirm without code in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253474/javascript-confirm-without-code-in-code-behind/8254073#8254073)

> That functionality you are expecting to perform that need some client
>   side JavaScript to server side code interaction. this may be possible
>   check [json.org](http://www.json.org). there are some libraries that perform such type
>   of functionality.

As you asked that if click on `Yes` then it will do some thing and if `No` then Update. you can do this using the `Ajax Controls`. if you are allowed to use them in your solution.

If you are not allowed to use them then create a `hidden field`, and set the value of that field based on the result of the confirmation.

**.aspx**

```
<input type="hidden" id="confirmResult" name="confirmResult" value="" />
<asp:Button  OnClientClick="ConfirmDialog();" 
    OnClick="OnServerClick" runat="server" />

<script>
   function ConfirmDialog() {
      var result = Confirm("Confirm Insert?");
      // set a flag to be submitted - "true"/"false"
      // or whatever suits
      document.getElementById("confirmResult").value = result; 
   }
```

**c#**

```
protected void OnServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    bool dialogResult = Convert.ToBoolean(confirmResult.Value);
if(dialogResult)
{
//Insert
}
else
{
//Update
}
}
```

Check this stackoverflow thread for more details:
[ASP.net - Button - Javascript Confirm dialog - execute SOME server-side code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155939/asp-net-button-javascript-confirm-dialog-execute-some-server-side-code)

Check this link - [AJAX Enabled MessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AJAX_Enabled_MessageBox.aspx) that i have used perform such functionality using the UserControl and Ajax, that get the confirmation result at the Server side Click event.

Have look on this, It is using `ClientClient` event of button etc but on this client side event it have used `ModalPopupExtender` ajax control.
[Confirm Message Box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/TipsnTricks/ConfirmMessageBox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"

onclientclick= "return confirm('Are You Sure To  Submit Record ?.')";

Or You can use

onclientclick="return(window.confirm('Are You Sure To Submit Record?'))" ;